# Angular 2 migration questions

Tags: angularjs, migration, watch, angular

I'd like to prepare our codebase for Angular 2 migration as much as possible. I understand that there isn't a solid migration strategy yet but still, there are two issues that I'm concerned about:

- Not using watches anymore.
- Not using two-way bindings anymore.

Let's say I have a directive that I want to keep updated according to model changes. How can I implement it without watches?

What if this directive is an interactive element and I want the model to reflect its changes? How can I do that without two-way bindings?

(If you have any other such problematic scenarios on mind please let's raise them and let's try to find solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't any pre-alpha version released yet we can only guess on how migrating could work. I found [this article](http://paislee.io/migrating-to-angularjs-2-0/) which helped me to understand the new concept a little better.